# from string to map object in Hive

Tags: hive, apache-hive

My input is a string that can contain any characters from A to Z (no duplicates, so maximum 26 characters it may have).

For example:-

```
set Input='ATK';
```

The characters within the string can appear in any order.

Now I want to create a map object out of this which will have ***fixed*** keys from **A** to **Z**. The value for a key is 1 if its corresponding character appears in the input string. So in case of this example (ATK) the map object should look like:-

[image: Map object]

So what is the best way to do this?

So the code should look like:-

```
set Input='ATK';
select <some logic>;
```

It should return a map object (`Map<string,int>`) with 26 key value pairs within it. What is the best way to do it, without creating any user defined functions in Hive. I know there is a function **str_to_map** that easily comes to mind.But it only works if key value pairs exist in source string and also it will only consider the key value pairs specified in the input.

Comment: It seems a lot more logical to store them  as `{1:[A, K, T], 0:[B, C, ..., Z]}`

Comment: That's alright. The question is about optimally determining whether each of the characters in the input string is there in the bigger string (A,B,C,...,Z). The actual input string is going to come from column value. Can you show using a sample query what logic you have in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not efficient but works:

```
select str_to_map(concat_ws('&',collect_list(concat_ws(":",a.dict,case when 
b.character is null then '0' else '1' end))),'&',':')
from 
(
   select explode(split("A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z",',')) as dict
) a 
left join
(
   select explode(split(${hiveconf:Input},'')) as character
) b 
on a.dict = b.character
```

The result:

```
{"A":"1","B":"0","C":"0","D":"0","E":"0","F":"0","G":"0","H":"0","I":"0","J":"0","K":"1","L":"0","M":"0","N":"0","O":"0","P":"0","Q":"0","R":"0","S":"0","T":"1","U":"0","V":"0","W":"0","X":"0","Y":"0","Z":"0"}
```